# Xamarin App not compiling after Xamarin Update

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

We have a Xamarin app running smoothly, but after latest update to Xamarin and Android Packages, we started receiving this error, the update changed Android Support version from 25.1.0 to 25.1.1:

```
Error: package android.support.v7.media.RemotePlaybackClient does not exist
```

check detail of error :

```
/Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.Droid/obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v7/media/RemotePlaybackClient_OnMessageReceivedListenerImplementor.java(48,48): Error:  error: package android.support.v7.media.RemotePlaybackClient does not exist
        android.support.v7.media.RemotePlaybackClient.OnMessageReceivedListener
warning: unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP
  reason: class file for android.support.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope not found
```

Adding Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter and Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please add the specific versions that you updated `from -> to`? This will help others figure out what the potential issue could be.

Answer (score 1):

For these sort of errors the safest option is to do the following:-

1) Gather a list of all the installed packages with their versions.

2) Remove all packages. Some packages will require removing other packages first.

3) Install all packages again.

Answer (score 0):

check dependencies for both packages.packageandroid.support.v7.media.RemotePlaybackClient,Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter because most of time dependecies should be updated.

Answer (score -1):

go to the nuget package manager and select all the package and push the Update butron in top of the page
Point: There are two update button